# Are there standards for flowcharting websites?

Tags: uml, flowchart

[image]

I had some trouble figuring out how to funnel users through different stages on a website I'm building and I figured that drawing a flowchart might help me see things clearer. So I started drawing a chart in [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) and an hour later I'd figured out what models and views I need to add and how to interconnect them. Given a little time, I can really see this kind of charting becoming a useful asset in my web development skill set.

One thing that bothered me though was the lack of symbols for common stuff related to web development. A symbol for forms would be nice. Maybe a way to indicate AJAX requests. I'm sure you can think of lots of other stuff. What are people using to visualise such things? Is there a standard set of symbols that I should use? I stumbled across UML years ago but never really got comfortable with it. Could that be used for charting web sites or is it not well suited to this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) to document the flow from page to page (including Ajax requests). Within a page, [activity diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) are often useful

For an excellent, short, and readable introduction to the use of UML, see [UML Distilled](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UML-Distilled-Standard-Modeling-Technology/dp/020165783X)

Comment: +1 for sequence diagrams, although I'm sure I used them (or something like them) long before I knew what UML was :-) When it comes to flowcharts, I've never found one "standard" that works, and I'm forever creating my own symbols to clearly illustrate a point...

Comment: +1 for activity diagrams/state diagrams.  Have found they work well, both for personal understanding and communicating with users/customers. I tend to view the whole site as a diagram, with each activity box representing a page.  Flows shows the primary linkages among pages.  Can also use swimlanes to illustrate multi-page journeys.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: Jesse James Garrett's [visual vocabulary for interaction architecture and design](http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/).

I don't use it personally, prefer using UML Activity/State diagrams.  However a few UX designers I know are strong advocates.  ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

I don't beleive there are official standards but the shapes never seem to differ likewise. For an operation use a box. Start and end use an oval. For a decision use a diamond. The graphical ones aren't standard, but can still be used.